# Icenium Kendo UI Datasource update not being called

Tags: jquery, json, kendo-ui

i'm quite new to kendo ui, i'm currently having trouble making the datasource run the sync for writing, by invoking the update action.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to read default data from a json file, and if any update to the data is made i would like to save it to local storage as json.

I was able to make the read working, and to display data, but for some reason i can't it make fire the update action with dataSource.sync()
my code is here

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            try {
                options.cached = false;
                //window.localStorage.removeItem("data");
                // window.localStorage.clear();
                // window.localStorage.setItem("data", null);
                var data = window.localStorage.getItem("data");

                if (data == null || data == undefined) {
                    console.log("ricarico");
                    data = new Object();


                    jQuery.getJSON("data/live.json", function (items) {
                        data.sections = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                        data.sections.push(new kendo.data.ObservableObject(items[i]));

                        options.success(data.sections);

                        window.localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
                    });
                } else {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("items " + data.sections[0].items.length);
                    options.success(data.sections);
                }


            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        },

        update: function (options) {
            try {
                console.log("try updated!");
                var data = window.localStorage.getItem("data");
                data.sections = options.data;
                window.localStorage.setItem("data", data);
                var result = getResult(options);
                options.success(result);
                console.log("updated!");
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("livegreen update: " + err.message);
            }
        },
        change: function (options) {
            console.log("change!");
        },
        destroy: function (options) {
            console.log("change!");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue my self, the problem is that if you don't define a schema  on the datasource, apparently the datasource can't fire update events.
so supposing your object have a primary key named id, your code should like that, see the added schema property.

```
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
           model: { id: "id" }
        },
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                try {
       .........................
```